# How to bypass systemd "start request repeated too quickly"

Tags: centos, redhat, systemd

I'm playing around with CHEF in a CentOS7 VM, and the script failed due to the issue:

```
systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for fail2ban.service
```

I know this is [configurable](https://serverfault.com/a/845473/293570) in systemd, but I'd just like to know, for testing purposes, if there is a way to "reset" systemd so I'm allowed to execute `start fail2ban service` without receiving this error forever. Right now I have to restart the OS so I'm able to execute it.

Thanks

Comment: It's better to _fix_ the problem than to "ignore" it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I'm just testing, even to find out what is happening it is useful to "reset" and be able to test again

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you really have some reason for restarting a service numerous times in a few seconds (or more likely, the service is misconfigured and failing to start) and are running into start limits, you can reset it by using `systemctl reset-failed <unit>`.

```
systemctl reset-failed fail2ban.service
```

Of course, you should fix whatever you did to the service configuration to cause it to fail to start properly.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error message was somewhat misleading.

The reason for the failure was found in the definition file. It resulted from a copy between machines. The line

```
User=my_user
```

in my service configuration file `/etc/systemd/system/infinite_script.service` was the culprit.

The new machine did not know of this user. Changing to `User=root` solved this problem.